# logical or | Unix

Tags: bash, unix, grep, logical-operators

I'm trying to realize a simple shell program that display french phone numbers contained in a file.

Here is my basic shell

```
#!/bin/bash

#search of phone numbers

t=( \+ | 00 )33[1-9][0-9]{8}
t2=( \+ | 00 )33[1-9][0-9]-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}
t3=( \+ | 00 )33[1-9][0-9].[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}

grep -e $1 ( $t | $t2 | $t3 )
```

Here is my input file :

phone_number.txt

```
+33143730862

00335.45.45.45.45

+332-45-45-45-45

+334545454554454545
```

I keep getting this errors :

```
./script_exo2.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./script_exo2.sh: line 5: `t=( \+ | 00 )33[1-9][0-9]{8}'
./script_exo2.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./script_exo2.sh: line 6: `t2=( \+ | 00 )33[1-9][0-9]-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
./script_exo2.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./script_exo2.sh: line 7: `t3=( \+ | 00 )33[1-9][0-9].[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}'
./script_exo2.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./script_exo2.sh: line 9: `grep -e $1 ( $t | $t2 | $t3 )'
```

Comment: You might want to put some quotes around strings and variables. http://www.shellcheck.net is your friend.

Comment: `bash` on OS X works the same as `bash` on any Linux you can find.  The script you presented is not valid on any of them, because it uses shell metacharacters and control operators unquoted where it wants them to be handled as data (in particular, `(`, `)`, `|`, and the space character).

Comment: `00` is not a universal international calling prefix, though it's correct in many countries.  That's why we need the universal `+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `t2` and `t3` have one more digit than the samples you're trying to match.  Also, you need to quote the arguments, and get rid of those spaces:

```
#!/bin/sh
t='(\+|00)33[1-9][0-9]{8}'
t2='(\+|00)33[1-9]-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
t3='(\+|00)33[1-9]\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}'

exec grep -E -e "$t|$t2|$t3" "$@"
```

1. I've used `sh` instead of `bash`, as we're not using any Bash features not available in standard POSIX shells (e.g. `dash`).
2. I've used single quotes above for the definitions of `t`, `t1` and `t2`, and double quotes where they are to be substituted.
3. I've told `grep` to understand Extended Regular Expressions via the `-E` flag, and I've put the pattern as the argument to the `-e` ("expression") flag to `grep`.
4. The `grep` process `exec`s in place of the shell, as there is no reason to fork for it.
5. I've passed the full set of input arguments `"$@"` so you can give extra options to `grep` (such as `-w`, `-n` or `-o`, for example), and choose whether to supply a file or stream stdin to your script.

Note also that if you're willing to accept a mix of `.`, `-` or nothing separating digit pairs, you can simplify your three expressions to just one:

```
(\+|00)33[1-9][0-9]([-.]?[0-9]{2}){4}
```

and the script becomes

```
#!/bin/bash
exec grep -E -e '(\+|00)33[1-9]([-.]?[0-9]{2}){4}' "$@"
```

If you need the delimiters to match, then you can use a capture group for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec grep -E -e '(\+|00)33[1-9]([-.]?)[0-9]{2}(\2[0-9]{2}){3}' "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.